# SSRS streamIDs and chart images render with same id for different requests

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Does anyone know if there is a way in the report definition to force a unique streamid for report images per request. I have a situation where I am rendering a report as a byte[] via the ReportExecutionsService web api. Whenever a report has images SSRS will give each image a streamid and I am required to save the parts to a temp web folder the client can access.

When I put a chart on a report the streamID never changes and this is causing a cache issue in browsers. The same chart displayed regardless of parameters, however, I can view the temp file on the server and see that the chart has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a workable solution in case anyone is interested.

A. Calculate the physical and virtual mapping to a temp folder in your controller methods.
    a. **NOTE : For reports with charts you should create a folder per request for the report**. I used:

```
private string GetVirtualTempFolder()
{
    if (Url != null)
        return Url.Content("~/Temp/");
    else
        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Temp/");    
}

private string GetPhysicalTempFolder()
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Temp\";
}
```

...

```
string virtualTempFolder = "";
string physicalTempFolder = "";
if (makeUniqueTempFolder)
{               

    virtualTempFolder = this.GetVirtualTempFolder();           
    physicalTempFolder = this.GetPhysicalTempFolder();
    string unique = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    virtualTempFolder = virtualTempFolder + unique + "/";
    physicalTempFolder = physicalTempFolder + unique + "/";
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalTempFolder);
}
```

B. Pass the directory names into your reporting services wrapper layer. I am using a DI so the signatures needed to be modified.

C. In the ReportingServices Rendering api you can pass the chosen virtual directory to pull temp files associated with streams via the **DeviceInfo** interface.

D. The streamIDs are returned in the Render method.  Iterate and save them to the calculated physical location.

While I already had the temp folder functionality working, I had to add the ability to optionally create a temp location per request.