# display reporting services report into asp.net web form

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

Hello everyone here you see my report in when i run it into my web service URL
but when i run it in an asp.net web form, it display like the second one why please
[image]

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("jean-daniel/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESSADDD") ' Report Server URL
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Project2/Auction" ' Report Name
    MyReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = True MyReportViewer.ShowPrintButton = True
    MyReportViewer.ShowToolBar = False MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh()
```

Comment: Could it be something like relative file references are not pointing to the proper place when put in a web form?

Comment: my code i don't know what is the problem where is the mistake as i run other form work well, only form that i have chart which make problem

Answer (score 0):

The charts are images and set to store one per session in cache. So if user a and user b access the same chart then it will come back as chart a. - a caching issue. I found a workaround noted below:

[Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055284/ssrs-streamids-and-chart-images-render-with-same-id-for-different-requests)

Comment: i think you didn't understand, what i want is that all the chart appear on the page on the web form